Elasticsearch to Slack integration: Pulling specific fields
I am currently trying to develop a slack channel for the use of alerting whenever I have a specific set of alerts that come in. I have been successful in getting a notification sent to the channel whenever the alert comes in, however, I am unable to have more specific information (Host name, Source IP, Event actions, etc.) included in the message unless I do the default {{alerts.all.data}} which just sends a raw format of the entire JSON to the channel. I admit that I am not the most experienced with this, but OSINT has not been fruitful
I already have the default "Rule {{context.rule.name}} generated {{state.signals_count}} alerts" and that works fine, but I am unable to figure out the syntax for other items that I wish to pull. Here are a few examples of my attempts:
{{context.observer.hostname}}
{{alerts.observer.hostname}}
{{observer.hostname}}
{{_source.observer.hostname}}
{{alerts._source.observer.hostname}}
For clarification, observer.hostname is a keyword field. However, that shouldn't affect if it can pull that data, right?
Any help would be appreciated!

You can customise your message with the following variable:

date
kibanaBaseUrl
rule.id
rule.name
rule name.
rule.params
rule.spaceId
rule.tags
rule.url

Those should always be available.
Then depending you the type of alert you are creating you might want to look into other fields such as:

context

To reference thos fields you are going to use the moustache syntax
